# Expand selection to next word Sublime Text 3 plugin

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

In Sublime Text, I know <kbd>Command + D</kbd> selects the current word and the next occurrence of it when you press the shortcut again.

What I'm searching for is a Sublime Text 3 plugin that assigns the following behavior to a keyboard shortcut:

1. First shortcut press, selects the current word (Exactly as <kbd>Command + D</kbd> does)
2. Second shortcut press, expands the selection to also include the next word (whatever that word is)

In short, I'm trying to simplify the following:

- <kbd>Command + D</kbd> (To select current word)
- <kbd>Alt + Shift + Right arrow</kbd> to expand selection so it includes the next word

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Preferences → Key Bindings ‐ User.
2. Add below lines to just opened file between `[` and `]`.

   ```
   { "keys": ["f1"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "subword_ends", "forward": true, "extend": true}},
   { "keys": ["f1"], "command": "find_under_expand", "context":
       [
           { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
       ]
   },
   ```
3. Change `f1` to any other shortcut key, if you want.